# Python uppercase conversion for a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one `.csv` file.

I want to convert the value of a particular column in my data set to upper case.

The values are `'Y'` and `'N'` and `'y'`.

I want to convert `'y'` to uppercase `'Y'`. Please  help.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something will this:

```
import csv
inFile = open('input.csv')
outFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
inReader = csv.reader(inFile)
outWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
for row in inReader:
   row[1]=row[1].upper()
   outWriter.writerow(row)
```

Using an input file, 'input.csv' like this:

```
first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth
a,       b,       c,    d,      e,    f
g,       h,       i,    j,      k,    l
```

You should get an output file, 'output.csv', like this:

```
first, SECOND, third, fourth, fifth, sixth
a,       B,       c,    d,      e,    f
g,       H,       i,    j,      k,    l
```

If you don't, let me know.